# Bounded geometry concept for non Levi-Civita connection

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors

Now at days the concept of a complete Riemannian manifold with bounded geometry is quite standard (see e.g. J. Cheeger,  M. Gromov, M. Taylor, Finite propagation speed, kernel estimates for functions of the laplace operator, and the geometry of complete riemannian manifolds). It consists of two conditions. One one hand, one ask for positivity of the injectivity radius; and on the other hand, there are two equivalent conditions:

a) Boundedness of the metric tensor and its derivatives on any geodesic ball,

b) Boundedness of the curvature tensor and its covariant derivatives.

This equivalence works because one is working with the Levi-Civita connection of the manifold. So I am wondering if anyone has ever seen this definition for more general connections, in particular I am interested in the case when the connection is not necessarily metric (it could be torsion-free). I think a possible definition could be the restriction on the injectivity radius, boundedness of the metric tensor and its derivatives, and boundedness of the Christoffel symbols and its derivatives. But I am not sure if this is really useful or not.

Thanks for any information.

Comment: You can still consider the curvature tensor of your connection, it is not specific to the LC connection. //

Note that if $\tilde{x}_i = \lambda x_i$ is a dilation of the coordinates, then the associated Christoffel symbols satisfy $\tilde{\Gamma}^{k}_{ij} = \frac{1}{\lambda}\Gamma^k_{ij}$. Similarly, one has $\tilde{\partial}_{\ell}\tilde{\Gamma}^k_{ij} = \frac{1}{\lambda^2}\partial_{\ell}\Gamma^k_{ij}$, and so on. I fear that one cannot bound the Christoffel symbols and their derivatives by constants that does not depend on the charts.

Comment: The question is what's your objective.

Comment: @MoisheKohan My objective is to have well defined function spaces like Sobolev, Besov, etc. For example, in H. Triebel Spaces of Besov-Hardy-Sobolev type on complete Riemannian manifolds, he defined those spaces working with the Levi-Civita connection and using the standard definition of bounded geometry. I think essentially one needs an specific partition of unity like in Proposition C of Triebel's paper. And I think that would work for other connections, but I don't know if anyone has seen it before

Comment: My suggestion for you is to start proving whatever you want to prove. At some point you will need extra conditions on your connection for your proof to work. These conditions will probably mean "bounded geometry." I do not think you will find anything in the literature beyond the L-C case.